# mySQL how can I speed up with function field > x and field < y

Tags: mysql

This is my query

```
SELECT PadID FROM Pads WHERE ((RemoveMeDate='2001-01-01 00:00:00') 
AND (catid in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)) AND ((ProgramName)<>'')) 
ORDER BY VersionAddDate DESC LIMIT 0,20;
```

Since I added

```
catID in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
```

Its slowed down a lot.

I've tried...

```
SELECT PadID FROM Pads WHERE RemoveMeDate='2001-01-01 00:00:00' AND 
catid >= 0 and catid <= 11 ORDER BY VersionAddDate DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

But thats just a slow.

I thought I might be able to you `coalesce` but I'm not sure how ?

Any ideas ?

EDITS

Categories table
[image]

Pad Table
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have to convince MySQL to filter on RemoveMeDate first.  Try:

```
SELECT  PadID 
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    Pads
        WHERE   RemoveMeDate = '2001-01-01 00:00:00' 
        ) as SubQuery
WHERE   catid >= 0 and catid <= 11 
ORDER BY 
        VersionAddDate DESC 
LIMIT   0, 20
```

Comment: @Jules: I thought you had an index on RemoveMeDate.  My answer makes no sense if you have an index on CatId

Comment: Ok, I put all the where clause in the sub query and only selected on padid, but the sub query approach fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using between

```
SELECT PadID FROM Pads WHERE RemoveMeDate='2001-01-01 00:00:00' AND 
catid between 0 and 11  ORDER BY VersionAddDate DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

Comment: See explain above, doesn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use between clause instead of >= <=.

```
catid between ? and ?
```

After you could add index in RemoveDate and catid

```
ALTER TABLE Pads ADD INDEX RemoveDate (RemoveDate);
```

Comment: I have an index already, heres the explain on that http://content.screencast.com/users/JulesM2010/folders/Jing/media/21a7a486-b359-42d6-8507-dfe9d21a9658/2010-11-09_1050.png

Answer (score 0):

Create a composite index on `(removemedate, catid)`.